# Configure replica set mongo from localhost to ip

Tags: mongodb

```js
 "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "localhost:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 1090,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1560235864, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(4)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-06-11T06:51:04Z"),
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1560234784, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2019-06-11T06:33:04Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 2,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                }
        ],
```

I am new to mongo replication , and i was trying to implement a replica set for mongo , for that i executed the `rs.initiate()` command, but i closed the terminal before adding the replica sets , now due to that i a primary node has been created with the hist as `localhost:27017` , but due to this i am not able to add other `hostnames`, because it says that either all references should be of localhost or none should be , due to which i am not able to add new instances, now since it is the only node i am not able to edit or delete it.

I read online that i need to reset the replica configuration by deleting some files , but is there any other way around it .

All i need to do is change the `hostname` of my only primary node fro `localhost` to `mongo-node-1`

Comment: Have a look at [Change Hostnames in a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-hostnames-in-a-replica-set/).

Comment: @vikscool i tried 'cfg = rs.conf();
cfg.members[0].host = "mongodb-node-1:27017";
rs.reconfig(cfg);'

Comment: but i am getting this error `No host described in new configuration 3 for replica set replicaSet maps to this node`

Comment: you can also set the `force` flag as `rs.reconfig(cfg,{force:true})` and also make sure you have the node named `mongodb-node-1` up and running.